# Inserting new item in tab under tab

Tags: .net, wpf, tags

How can I add new items in a tab which is already belongs in another tab's canvas ? i tried normally... but when i start debugging, the output window shows me nothing.

Answer (score 0):

As I know, all items (read controls) which are UIElement should have only one parent. May be you have to implement method, which will retrive data about items you have, and it will create new items which you should use in your new tab.